# get_group users returning 500 internal server error

Tags: box-api

I'm using the v1 version of the API. When I make a call to get_group_users, I'm getting a 500 internal server error response back. It has been working in the past - is this a new issue?

Incidentally, returning this page for an API call breaks XML formatting (we noticed this from an error message "string "--" is not permitted within comments" when trying to parse the response body.

Answer (score 0):

We also had the same issue suddenly with the API V1.  When we investigated the issue with the API team it was for us to do with the size of the result.

There was no solution for us but to move to the API V2 which by default pages results and hence caps the issue.

However as you are aware Groups are not get exposed in the new API but I understand they are coming and just in the backlog along with the other missing features that can be found in API V1.

I am sure one of the API developers reading this can give some advice on an ETA for Groups reaching GA in API V2

Comment: Actually groups is the only v1 api that supports pagination.  So you may want to try sending in page and page_size to your v1 groups request.